# When creating a subclass in Javascript, why assign prototype fields?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

[Mozilla's Javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) say that this is a good way to create objects:

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

rect instanceof Rectangle; // true
rect instanceof Shape; // true

rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

However, when practicing, I intentionally skipped the lines

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

and all the behaviour seemed totally normal. It seems like there were no consequences of skipping those lines. For example, I still created `Rectangle` objects, called its properties, etc.

Are those lines superfluous? What am I missing?

Comment: Without those lines, the tests would work differently. I suggest you re-try the tests.

Comment: [I can't verify your observation](http://jsfiddle.net/29bk90gd/): `TypeError: rect.move is not a function` also, `rect instanceof Shape` is `false`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

This line enables you to use prototype methods of Shape objects with your Rectangle objects.

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

This should not work when you skip the line mentioned above, because you still create Rectangle objects, and you still have a Rectangle prototype, but you do not use the prototype of Shape as the base prototype for your Rectangle objects and as a result no `Shape.prototype.move` should be available.

```
rect instanceof Shape; // true
```

Also, as ProgramFOX said, this line will not result in `true` if you remove the above line.

Here is the snippet with the mentioned changes:

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.log('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

Rectangle.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    console.log('Rectangle alert.');
}

// subclass extends superclass
//Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log(rect instanceof Shape); // Does NOT output true
rect.doSomething(); // DOES output 'Rectangle alert.'
rect.move(1, 1); // Does NOT output 'Shape moved.'
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why it's `Shape.call(this)` and not `Shape(this)`?

Comment: @Imray, the call function is used because you want to execute the Shape constructor from within the Rectangle constructor but supply the current object (a Rectangle!) as `this` argument to the Shape constructor. Call ([LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) enables you to do this (first argument is the `this` argument). As a result also Rectangles get `this.x` and `this.y` as implemented in the Shape constructor, because the `this` object is actually the one that is given to `Shape.call(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove those lines, `rect instanceof Shape` will return `false`.

The following snippet writes `rect instanceof Shape` if those lines are commented out.

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
// lines commented out:
//Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
//Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

rect instanceof Rectangle; // true
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (rect instanceof Shape).toString();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why it's `Shape.call(this)` and not `Shape(this)`?

Comment: @Imray Probably the people who defined the JS spec decided to do it that way, but I don't know the reasons for that.